# Unity C# - Azure Blob Service stops working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an issue with my c# code. I am developing an application in HoloLens using Unity and C# and I was planning on using Azure Blob Storage as a database for my files. To load the files in the application, until few days ago, I was using the package StorageService (https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/StorageServices) to list my containers in the storage account and load all the files.
Suddenly, while I was using it, the Debug started to give some warning messages:

```
Response error status:0 code:0 error:Response failed with status: 0 request url:https://<mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&restype=container
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
RESTClient.RestRequest:ParseXML<Azure.StorageServices.ContainerResults> (System.Action`1<RESTClient.IRestResponse`1<Azure.StorageServices.ContainerResults>>) (at C:/Users/.../RestRequest.cs:256)
Azure.StorageServices.BlobService/<ListContainers>d__2:MoveNext () (at C:/Users/.../BlobService.cs:31)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
```

Apparently, there is some code error 0 that I can't understand and I did not find anything on this website.

I tried to check the access keys and all the settings in Azure, but I did not change anything in months and I did not have these issues.

Do you know any way to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I solved the issue. It was a matter of connection given by the Parallels Desktop on my Mac.
I also changed the library because the mentioned one was not working.

Comment: Have you change something on your side? Did you reinstall the OS or some needed software recently? Did you upgrade some packages that were linked to your application?

Comment: @vaitrafra actually no, I just kept using the package that I had. In addition, Azure is working if I am using a python code but not with Unity, i tried to change the keys but it does not seem a problem of permissions.

Comment: Update: I tried to change storage account and now the message changed to 'Forbidden' even if the access key is right

Comment: Can you update your code to your question?